# What is the strongest means to force MS Word to not underrun a minimum table column width

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, column

As is generally known, desired column widths in a Word table can be set in the table properties individually for each column in centimeters or percent:

[image: Word Table Properties dialog]

However, experience shows that Word does not adhere to this reliably, or permanently.

Then it is possible, for example, to insert a series of protected blanks that is as wide as the desired minimum column width, into the column. This seems to help fairly reliably.

However, line breaks and thus undesired reduction of such protected column widths can still occur, depending on the view mode (Web Layout, Print Layout) or window width.

Are there other, even stronger tools or hacks to absolutely force a minimum column width?

Ideally, a subset of the columns in a table should be protected this way, while the remaining columns should be allowed to automatically adapt to the available window/viewport width.

Comment: This might require VBA, which will be pretty complicated to do.

Comment: You can search the Internet for related plugins or add-ins.

Comment: Also uncheck the "automatically resize to fit contents" in the table options dialog box